# how to send back asynchronous request to viewDidLoad method

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, alamofire

i'm new on programming and of course swift. and i'm wondering how can i send back my request response to my viewDidLoad to to use there.
for requesting, i'm using alamofire and for json , swiftyJSON.
what i'm trying to do is to Get data(JSON) from server which contains titles and image urls. after that i'm trying to Get images from image urls.
 in viewDidLad, i call a function which is a Get method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getData()
    //use myStruct
```

in getData() i do this:

```
func getData()
{
    Alamofire.request(.GET,"heregoesurl")
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let Json = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(Json)
                for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
                    //get image url
                    //pass image url to imageGet() method 
                    //add image to an array of myStruct
                }

                }
            }
    }
```

and in imageGet() method:

```
func getImages(url:String,type:String)
{
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
        .responseImage { response in
            if let image = response.result.value {
                //add image to myStruct
            }
    }
}
```

the problem is because of async nature of request, myStruct isn't ready in viewDidLoad. i used completionHandler for getData() method and it works fine. but still i don't have images and i just have image urls there. i don't know what should i do then.

any help on how to do things like this would be appreciated.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38417602/5654848). I've explained how to use completion handlers. You are not using it properly.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 actually i didn't use completion in my posted code. i meant i used it but in what i've posted i didn't use them. the real question for me is that how can i get images with different urls and use them while i'm in my getData() completion handler

Comment: is myStruct your custom struct?  can you just init it be for calling the getData()?

Comment: @JoeyEtamity yes. it's a struct i defined. and init it before calling getData()

Comment: If the image urls are being retrieved in the getData() then it seems getImages should be called inside the completion block of Alamofire.request(.GET,"heregoesurl")

Comment: @HosAp I think you can call getImage() inside the getData()
Would you like to share you source code ?  I will help you to sort it

Comment: @JoeyEtamity of course. how can i share? edit the post ?

Comment: @AndrewMcKinley actually i tested it but the problem is if i call inside completion block , still i don't know how can i use results from getImages()

Comment: The completion block of getImages should call another method that takes the results of getImages().

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public func getImages(url:String,type:String){
     Alamofire.request(.GET, url).response { (request, response, data, error) in
        //For sure that you will have the main queue and you will see the view
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
            self.myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data, scale:1) // or store it to your `myStruct`
        })
  }
}
```

call it inside of getData() function

Comment: in my case, that doesn't solve the problem. anyway, i handled it with some tricks. thanks for your time ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
extension UIImageView {

func downloadImage(from url : String){

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest){(data,response,error)in

        if error != nil {  
            print(error)  
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = UIImage(data:data!)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
}
```